# Making a chart from table in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, document

I'm making an internal tool to automate reports, from frontend to Word, and what I'm looking for is a way to create charts from in-document tables, such as the following:
[image]

The default way is opening embedded and Excel such as the following:
[image]

However, this way won't work, since the tool can replace fields in Word, but not in embedded Excels. **Macros won't work** since the tool disables them by default for security reasons. I'm looking for something like dynamics fields such as sequence generators or formulas, but can't come up with anything. Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/drawing-and-graphics/50189-making-chart-table-ms-word.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

«**Macros won't work** since the tool disables them by default for security reasons.» Your premise is false. For example:

```
Sub ChartDemo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, r As Long, c As Long
With ActiveDocument
  Set Tbl = .Tables(1)
  With .InlineShapes(1)
    If .HasChart Then
      .Chart.ChartData.Activate
      With .Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1)
        For r = 2 To Tbl.Rows.Count
          For c = 2 To Tbl.Columns.Count
            .Cells(r, c).Value = Split(Tbl.Cell(r, c).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
          Next
        Next
      End With
      .Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit
    End If
  End With
End With
Set Tbl = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: When I said that the tool disables them, I meant our internal tool, not office itself. There is no way around enabling macros, that's why I can't rely on them

Comment: Well, whatever software your tool is written in should have the capacity to do exactly the same thing - using the same methods - as the VBA code above. It's just a matter of getting your IT folk to add that capability. Of course, the above code assumes you're working with the first table and the first chart and those assumptions won't necessarily be valid in all cases.