# VBA in Microsoft word. Input Table and Output Table

Tags: vba, ms-word, user-input

Im trying to create a form where I can fill in 10 variables into an input table, and this will populate an output table depending on combinations of inputs. I have written some code that i cannot for the life of me figure out why it wont work. My input table, table1, has 2 columns and 10 rows, and my output table has 3 columns and 20 rows.

This is the code so far. It is a basic start to try and get at least the first output to work, and will then be developed to include all variables.

```
Sub SelectInputsAndOutputs()

    Dim tbl1 As Table, tbl2 As Table
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    Dim input1 As String, input2 As String

    ' Set tbl1 to the first table in the document
    Set tbl1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    ' Set tbl2 to the second table in the document
    Set tbl2 = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)

    ' Loop through each row in tbl1
    For row = 1 To tbl1.Rows.Count
        ' Set rng to the second cell in the current row
        Set rng = tbl1.Cell(row, 2).Range
        ' Read the input value from rng and store it in the appropriate variable
        If row = 1 Then
            input1 = rng.Text
        ElseIf row = 2 Then
            input2 = rng.Text
        End If
    Next

    ' Calculate the output value based on the inputs
    Dim output As String
    If input1 = "PiP" And input2 = "CMn" Then
        output = "Min:11.7"
    ElseIf input1 = "PiP" And input2 = "13Cr" Then
        output = "13Cr is the best"
    End If

    ' Write the output value to the third column of tbl2
    tbl2.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = output

    End Sub
```

Basically, nothing happens. My Tables look like this:

```
---------------------
:Type    :PiP     :
------------------
:Design  : 13Cr   :
-------------------
```

and so on.....

My output table is just a blank 3x20 table.

Comment: Ok, tried to split the input text, and added a debug for both input and output. VBA recognises the true inputs, however it doesnt recognise the output.

Comment: This is because a table cell's rng.text is terminated by an end-of-cell marker which you have to remove frm your input1 and input2 strings for your comparisons to work. It's a *very* common problem.

Comment: «This is because a table cell's rng.text is terminated by an end-of-cell marker which you have to remove frm your input1 and input2 strings for your comparisons to work. It's a very common problem» For one such approach, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75005037/making-a-chart-from-table-in-ms-word

Comment: Hi, thanks to you both. 

I have tried this:

'    If row = 1 Then
            input1 = Replace(rng.Text, " ¤ ", " ")
        ElseIf row = 2 Then
            input2 = Replace(rng.Text, " ¤ ", " ")
        End If
'
Still no joy. I put these lines in to see if it was being deleted:
'
If InStr(input1, "¤") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unversal one "
        ElseIf InStr(input1, "$") > 0 Then MsgBox "Dollar sign one"
        Else
            MsgBox "its deleted"
    End If
'
It appears that it is being deleted.

Comment: The end-of-cell marker consists of two characters, chr(13)+chr(7).

Comment: You beauty, thanks for the help! @jonsson